# get formatted html snippet (without stripping tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

Is there a way to get text snippet from a html document without removing the format(tag)?
Suppose you are given a following document:

```
<h3> Hello World </h3>

<p>
You see this world quite often. 
You must take the blue pill here blah blah...
</p>
```

You want to extract first 30 characters with the formatting tags included:

```
<h3> Hello World </h3>

<p>
You see this world quite often.
You must take the blue...
</p>
```

javascript/jquery, python, language-agonostic strategry are all welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this github project https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten It does what you want.

Comment: looking at the project. Thanks.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

*extract first 30 characters with the formatting tags*

With jquery i would do this:

```
$('<p/>', {
   text : $('p').text(function(){ return this.textContent.slice(0, 30) })
}).replaceWith('p');
```

---

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EM8wC/)

---

If you want to target `p` tags of specific block then you can do this:

```
$('<p/>', {
   text : $('#div p').text(function(){ return this.textContent.slice(0, 30) })
}).replaceWith('p');
```

#### [Within a context demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/EM8wC/1/)

Comment: yeah! right, but as OP suggested in the question to extract the first 30 characters with tags, so i think if he has more `p` tags then those will be replaced with this. so instead OP can give a context to replace only within that context.